# sharing memory between C# and native C++

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, managed, native-code

is there a way to share memory between managed and native code, just like memory mapped files (I'am using .Net 2.0, so MMF is not available in this version), I'am new to this .Net, so what is actually marshalling? I've done this for communication between managed and unmanaged code, but my question is during marshaling do we copy the memory portion of unmanaged to managed memory area, or we share the same address space, thus when we change a variable from unmanaged code, then the value is changed too in managed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx.) is a useful start point to gain some ideas about Marshaling between Managed and Unmanaged Code

you can skip the part related to [InAttribute] and [OutAttribute]

Comment: Link to post broken on 12 June 2018